# Image width 'malfunctioning' on hover (webkit), how to fix it?

Tags: html, css, image, webkit, width

I make tumblr themes (though I'm not a professional nor a student in any way, I learnt what I know by messing around) and I've been struggling with a 'malfunction' regarding post images.

Basically when you hover on a post, the images 'lose' a few px to the right just to 'get them back' after a few seconds, and this is affecting both full images and the eventual image padding - this only happening in webkit browsers.

Here's an example: 
http://songbirdtheme8.tumblr.com/

and the code:
http://pastebin.com/XZgihVeX

If you scroll down the page you can see that the picture of cotton candy is not affected by this. I'd like to know:

1. Why is the whole thing happening?
2. How to fix it?

Comment: Please post the relevant code here, not linking to it.

Comment: Try and narrow down the problem rather than showing all the code for the entire page

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution but I can't exactly tell what the problem is.

1. Here's the solution: `#post img { padding-right: 0 }`
2. (not related) You shouldn't use the same id for multiple elements, you should turn #post, into .post (you'll have to figure out why by yourself)